# Aurelia oneTime binding Behaviour

Tags: aurelia

I want to know why Aurelia oneTime binding is behaving like this.
I have an HTML like this.

```
<span> ${dbaName & oneTime}</span>
<input type="text" value.bind="dbaName" spellcheck="false" />
```

My View-model is like this in typescript and after the success of ajax call i am assigning the value to dbaName :

```
export class VendorGeneral 
{
      dbaName:string;
      constructor()
      {
      }

      activate()
      {
        $.ajax({
          url: "servicecall",
          context: document.body
        }).done(function() {
          this.dbaName = "DATA ADMIN";
        });
      }
}
```

Now What HTML will show the output as:

```
<span> ${dbaName & oneTime}</span> **blank**
<input type="text" value.bind="dbaName" spellcheck="false" /> **DATA ADMIN**
```

In Span, I will get blank value or an empty string whereas in the textbox I will get Data Admin as a value which is correct.

Please let me know why **oneTime** bind is giving empty string and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The `oneTime`, as the name suggest, will bind only once and all further changes will be ignored. When the view is rendered, the value of `dbaName` is `undefined`. So, the span's content will be `undefined`, which is equals to  'nothing';

I see that you're using `activate`, but you're using in the wrong way. If you want the view to be rendered after the return of the ajax call, you have to return a promise in the activate method. Something like:

```
activate {
   return yourPromise()
     .then(() => this.dbaName = 'admin');
}
```

I recommend you to use `aurelia-fetch-client` instead of `$.ajax`. If you still want to use `$.ajax` you can try this (untested code):

```
activate() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "servicecall",
    context: document.body
  }).then(() => {
    this.dbaName = "DATA ADMIN";
  });
}
```